# Ye olde UnicodeEncodeError printing results from a query on MS SQL with adodbapi

Tags: python, unicode, adodbapi

Python novice here.

I am using python2.7.2 on Windows7.

I have installed the PyWin32 extensions (build 217).

I have adopdbapi installed in `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\adodbapi`

I have a very simple module that queries the AdventureWorks2008LT database in MS SQL Server.

```
import adodbapi

connStr='Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;' \
    'Integrated Security=SSPI;' \
    'Persist Security Info=False;' \
    'Initial Catalog=AVWKS2008LT;' \
    'Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS'

conn = adodbapi.connect(connStr)

tablename = "[salesLT].[Customer]"

# create a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# extract all the data
sql = "select * from %s" % tablename
cur.execute(sql)

# show the result
result = cur.fetchall()
for item in result:
    print item

# close the cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The AdventureWorks2008LT sample database has customer, product, address, and order tables (etc). Some of the string data in these tables is unicode.

The query works, *for the first couple rows*. I see the expected output. But then, the script fails with this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\python\query-1.py", line 24, in <module>
    print item
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 651, in __str__
    return str(tuple([str(self._getValue(i)) for i in range(len(self.rows.converters))]))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

...which is very much not helpful. To me.

I gather that adodbapi is trying to encode a u'\xe9' character into ASCII.  I understand why that will fail. 
I suppose it's trying to do that as part of the `print` statement.

Why is it trying to encode the character into ASCII?
How can I tell it to just use UTF-8?

ps: I am running the script from the cmd.exe prompt in Windows. Does this mean stdout is always ASCII?

eg, `\python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"`

gives me 'cp437'

Comment: I don't have your answer, but +1 just for the name. :)

Comment: If adodbapi doesn't have a feature toggle for this, you're going to have to edit/monkey-patch it. The fault lies, as the stack trace shows, on line 651 of adodbapi.py, where they attempt to call `str` on a Unicode string...

Comment: @Borealid - I was thinking it might be because I am running the python script from the `cmd.exe` window.  Which may not be unicode-capable.

Comment: @Cheeso You can set the system locate to a UTF-8 one, but that won't fix the fact that in Python 2.7, strings are one-byte-per-character. You have to use a unicode object to correctly store any characters above 256, and what a character from 128-256 represents is encoding dependent. So, at best, you'd get data corruption...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the script to run to completion, printing all retrieved rows, by modifying the output portion to do this:

```
# show the result
result = cur.fetchall()
for item in result:
    print repr(item)
```

instead of this:

```
# show the result
result = cur.fetchall()
for item in result:
    print item
```

So the problem is in fact the use of `str` within adodbapi as Borealid said in a comment. But that is not necessarily a blocking problem. Normally when retrieving rows from a database query, people don't simply want a string representation of a row; they want to retrieve the values in the individual columns. My conclusion is that this problem is sort of an artificial problem, due to the way I was building a test app.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell it to just use UTF-8?

```
chcp 65001
```